# Django model instance with changes from QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

There is model instance:

```
business = Business.objects.get(id=1)
```

I have `QueryDict` with changed data in `ModelForm` based on above model (I have only the fields which has different values):

```
>>> print(data)
<QueryDict: {u'city': [u'26364'], u'name': [u'New name'], u'phone': [u'123456789']}>
```

How to update model instance with the values updated from `QueryDict`? I think about using ModelForm in that way:

```
form = BusinessForm(data, instance=business)
if form.is_valid():
     updated_business = form.save(commit=False)
```

But there is a problem with validation, because `data` does not contain all required fields.

Is there any not very complicated way of doing it? Maybe something like dumping `business` data fields to `QueryDict`, then merge this dictionary with `data`, and then use above code to build form?